# Why does this first-order RC filter with an op-amp display resonance?

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter

I built this circuit and simulated it in CircuitLab and was trying to make an active low pass filter. However, it shows a frequency response like a resonant low pass filter and I can't figure out why.

Here's the schematic:
[image: Here's the schematic]
And the frequency response:
[image: Plot of the frequency response]

The gain of the frequencies below the resonant frequency is set by the ratio of R2/R1 (x10 with these values), as expected for an inverting op-amp circuit. But I can't figure out why there is the resonant peak at 800 Hz for this first-order circuit, or how to calculate the resonant frequency.

And the response of a few different cap values:
[image: Sweep of cap values]

And the response of different values of R1:
[image: Sweep of R1 values]

Changing the value of R1 has no effect on the resonant frequency, only on the gain of the circuit. I don't understand why this circuit behaves this way. **Can anyone explain it to me?**

I came up with this equation for the value of \$V_{out}\$:

$$V_{out} = -( \frac{A \times R2}{R1 + R2 + R1R2Cs - A \times R1} ) V_{in} $$

Does this equation look right? It makes sense to me that when \$(R1 + R2 + R1R2Cs) << A \times R1 ,\$ the result is approximately equal to R2 / R1. But I have no idea where the peak at 800 Hz comes from.

Comment: It is obviously not a first-order circuit, as first order circuits cannot exhibit resonance. Suggest you try to include the pole in the op-amp response. It's usually at something like 10Hz.

Comment: How do I do that?  Are you saying that the second order behavior is due to a parasitic capacitance?

Comment: No, it's because the op-amp has a capacitor inside it for frequency compensation (to make it stable with unity gain). Above the pole frequency, the op-amp gain drops by -20dB/decade. Sometimes there's a second pole.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, if you assume that the internals of the op-amp contain, in effect, a first order low pass filter, you will have created for yourself what is known as a multiple feedback low-pass filter.  I used a great simulation tool from Mister Okawa [here](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPttool.php) to produce this: -

[image]

If you look closely at the circuit in the picture above and imagine that R2 and C2 are inside the op-amp, your circuit becomes the same. There is some hand-waving here because I'm taking a stab in the dark about what R2 and C2 actually are and "massaging" them numerically to fit close to producing a peak near 800 Hz.

C2 being 5pF is in the right order for the "conventional" stabilizing stage inside an old-fashioned op-amp like the TL081 and I guess R2 would be in the vicinity of a few kohm.

Anyway I'm convinced this is what is happening!!!

Comment: Very nice and innovative application of a existing tool.

Comment: Agree with above comment.  But does this mean that any active filter with any op-amp, or a TL081 at the least, is technically a second (or third)-order Sallen-Key?  And could it also be due to parasitic capacitance of the transistors in the op-amp?

Comment: Scratch out "is technically" since Sallen-Key is a topology - replace with "has the response characteristics of".  I'm mostly wondering whether this phenomenon would apply to most or even all other op-amps to some degree...

Comment: Well, it's more like an MFB topology and yes this can happen. If you push the design of any topology filter using op-amps you will find that the lack of infinite bandwidth will give problems like these and they can even turn oscillatory.

Comment: OK, so, yes, but the effect will often be negligible to non-existent, depending on - well, everything else, including the specs/design of the op-amp used - if I'm following correctly.

Comment: Usually yes, non existent if you don't expect to build a 10MHz filter using 741 op amps (for example).